# Running a function from spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a newbie to spring boot.
Is there some way that I can invoke a function from a spring-boot jar in an application?

I have exported a spring-boot project as jar. Inside the service class, there is a function that interacts with a database, using SpringJPA. Also, it uses a variable that is initialized using @Value.

This is my service class:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    private TestRepo repo;
    @Value("#{new Double('${property.value})}")
    private double val;

    public double myFunc(int a, int b) {
        double res = a*val + b;
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
        entity.setValue(res);
        repo.saveAndFlush(entity);
        return res;
    }
}
```

This is my repo:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Integer> {

}
```

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private int id; //  Autogenerated
    private double value;
}
```

I want to access
`new TestService().myFunction(10,20)`
from another project. Currently, it is throwing NullPointerException for repo, and initializing val with 0. I guess this is happening because the service bean was never initialized, as the boot application was never started.

Is there some way I can access such functionality, other than using REST API calls to a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controllers endpoints are the entry point to your services. In reality your boot app run inside a container and to use the service you have to expose the endpoint and autowire your services. Not sure if there is a practical use case of the scenario you are looking for.

Comment: Can this scenario work if I am trying to access function like this from another spring boot project?

Comment: Nope. You will have to make a Feign Call to the other boot endpoint.